# Python compare a list of objects against a query set for two matching values?

Tags: python, django

I have created list of objects which holds my live VPN data. I also have VPN data store in a DB.

I want to be able to compare the list of live Data objects against the DB, if data matches then do 'something'

if an object is anyconnect the usernames will match against the DB, if an object is site to site, then the peer its will match against the BD

I need to go through the list of objects and find the matches

basically what I'm doing is comparing the live data against the DB data, if the live data is found in the DB I will update the DB record to say the service is 'Up' if it is not found, the service will be 'Down'

can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

EDIT:

list of live data

```
>>> for i in active_vpns:
...  print('username: {} peer_ip: {}'.format(i.username,i.peer_ip))
username: remote_vpn.user1: 1.2.3.4
username:  peer_ip: 1.1.1.1
username:  peer_ip: 2.2.2.2
username:  peer_ip: 3.3.3.3
```

list of DB data

```
>>> vpn_services = ThirdPartyService.objects.all()
>>>  for i in vpn_services:
...  print('username: {} peer_ip: {}'.format(i.username,i.peer_ip))
username: remote_vpn.user1: 1.2.3.4
username: remote_vpn.user2: 1.2.3.5
username:  peer_ip: 1.1.1.1
username:  peer_ip: 2.2.2.2
username:  peer_ip: 3.3.3.3
username:  peer_ip: 4.4.4.4
```

now in this instance I would want to set peer_ip 4.4.4.4 as Down and remote_vpn.user2 as Down and the rest of the services set to Up

Full Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django_setup import setup
setup()
import re
import ipaddress
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from monitoring.models import ThirdPartyService
from datetime import datetime

class VPNData(object):
    def __init__(self, service_name='', username='', vpn_peer_ip='', duration='', data_transmit='', data_receive='', timestamp=''):
        self.service_name = service_name
        self.username = username
        self.vpn_peer_ip = vpn_peer_ip
        self.duration = duration
        self.data_transmit = data_transmit
        self.data_receive = data_receive
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.username)   

def to_megabytes(bytes, bsize=1024):
    r = float(bytes)
    for i in range(2):
        r = r / bsize
    return round(r)

#creds for logging on to devices
username = 'monitoring'
password = '*******'
device_ip = '10.10.10.10'

# firewall conenction details
firewall = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_asa',
        'ip':   device_ip,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'port' : 22,        # optional, defaults to 22
        'secret': '',       # optional, defaults to ''
        'verbose': False,   # optional, defaults to False
    }  
# connect to firewall
conn_fw = ConnectHandler(**firewall)
# get anyconnect sessions
anyconnect_connections = conn_fw.send_command('show vpn-sessiondb anyconnect')  
# get site to site vpn sessions
s2s_connections = conn_fw.send_command('show vpn-sessiondb l2l')  
# disconnect ssh session
conn_fw.disconnect()

active_vpns =[]
# create list of anyconnect sessions
anyconnect_sessions = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Username     :)(.*?)(?=Security Grp)', anyconnect_connections, flags=re.S)
# process anyconnect sessions
for ac_sess in anyconnect_sessions:
    # create object for data    
    vpn = VPNData()
    # get username
    username = re.findall(r'(?s).*?(?=Index)', ac_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.username = username[0].strip()
    # get peer ip
    peer_ip = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Public IP    : )(.*?)(?=Protocol)', ac_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.peer_ip = peer_ip[0].strip()
    # get duration
    duration = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Duration     : )(.*?)(?=Inactivity)', ac_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.duration = duration[0].strip()
    # transmit bytes
    data_transmit = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Bytes Tx     : )(.*?)(?=Bytes Rx)', ac_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.data_transmit = data_transmit[0].strip()
    # receive bytes
    data_receive = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Bytes Rx     : )(.*?)(?=Group Policy)', ac_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.data_receive = data_receive[0].strip()
    # Add VPN to List
    active_vpns.append(vpn)

# Add extra string to get the last connection
s2s_connections += 'Connection'
# create list of sie to site vpn sessions
s2s_sessions = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Connection   :)(.*?)(?=Connection)', s2s_connections, flags=re.S)
# process site to site sessions
for s2s_sess in s2s_sessions:
    # create object for data
    vpn = VPNData()
    # get peer ip
    peer_ip = re.findall(r'(?s).*?(?=Index)', s2s_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.peer_ip = peer_ip[0].strip()
    # get duration
    duration = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Duration     : ).*', s2s_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.duration = duration[0].strip()
    # transmit bytes
    data_transmit = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Bytes Tx     : )(.*?)(?=Bytes Rx)', s2s_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.data_transmit = data_transmit[0].strip()
    # receive bytes
    data_receive = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Bytes Rx     : )(.*?)(?=Login Time)', s2s_sess, flags=re.S)
    vpn.data_receive = data_receive[0].strip()
    active_vpns.append(vpn)

# get list of VPNs from DB
vpn_services = ThirdPartyService.objects.all()
for service in vpn_services:


    vpn_data = ThirdPartyService.objects.update_or_create(
            defaults={
                'service_name' : 'anyconnect',
                'username' : username,
                'vpn_peer_ip' : peer_ip,
                'duration' : duration,
                'data_transmit' : to_megabytes(data_transmit),
                'data_receive' : to_megabytes(data_receive),
                'timestamp' : datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                },
            service_name = 'anyconnect',
            username = username
        )




print('{0} Script Completed'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')))
```

Comment: Can you extract the relevant part of code?

Comment: @Don tried to clear it up, hopefully this makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build a `dict` or a `set` from DB entries and then use it to test active connections.

Something like:

```
db_peer_ips = set(ThirdPartyService.objects.values_list('peer_ip', flat=True))
for i in active_vpns:
     status = 'Up' if i.peer_ip in db_peer_ips else 'Down'
     print('username: {} peer_ip: {} status: {}'.format(i.username, i.peer_ip, status))
```